# Custom Event not working

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I have created a Custom Event, that is fired from a custom component. It should be catched in the main application to change the selectedindex of the viewstack.
But this doesn't work, and I can't figure out why.

This is my Custom Event:

```
package events
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class ChangeSelectedIndex extends Event
    {
        public static var index_passed:String = "Index passed";
        private var index:int;

        public function ChangeSelectedIndex(i:int, type:String, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
        {
            super(type,bubbles, cancelable);
            index = i;
        }

        public function get getIndex():int
        {
            return index;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I fire the event:

```
protected function checkUsernameExistsDbSucces(event:ResultEvent):void
{
     dispatchEvent( new ChangeSelectedIndex(1,ChangeSelectedIndex.index_passed,false,false));
}
```

And this is my function to catch the event:

```
private function changeSelectedIndexHandler(event:ChangeSelectedIndex):void
{
     mainViewStack.selectedIndex = event.getIndex;
}
```

Comment: You're certain `checkUsernameExistsDbSucces` is called? Have you tried to trace the call?

Comment: Where do you add the event listener?  If the event isn't caught at all, you either don't dispatch one (the function isn't called), you listen to the wrong event dispatcher, or your event should be bubbling.

Comment: @JohnGiotta: Yes, this is succesfully called.

Comment: @weltraumpirat: I realize I haven't added an eventListener. Where should I do this best?

Comment: Just a side note: you should include word `Event` in your custom event class name. Now it seems that you've named it by what it does, not what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for your handler to be called when the event is dispatched, you need to add an event listener to your custom component.

```
myCustomComponent.addEventListener ( ChangeSelectedIndex.index_passed, changeSelectedIndexHandler);
```

Make sure this line is within the same scope as both your handler function and myCustomComponent, otherwise there will be an error.